# Run vbs script in batch file

Tags: vbscript

I read an article to use a vbs script to access the CTL+ALT+DEL to change password GUI. I named it "ChangePWD.vbs"

```
 Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
     objShell.WindowsSecurity()
```

And I write cscript ChangePWD.vbs but it does not work to me. Did I miss something ?

---

This one also not works. Any Help.
[image: CHANGEPASSWORDS_GUI]

> 

```
 function fnIShellDispatch4WindowsSecurityVB()
    dim objShell
    
    set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
        objShell.WindowsSecurity
    set objShell = nothing
end function
```

Comment: As per [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-windowssecurity) this method will work only in a terminal session. <quote>This method can be used only when connected by a terminal session to Microsoft Terminal Server.</quote>

Comment: Is there any other alternative to make it ?